# Aligning images with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, image, openpyxl

I have been looking for a couple days now and cannot find an answer. I am creating a worksheet with python and is using the openpyxl module. I am able to format cells and insert values in the cells. I can insert images in cells, but i need to align the images.

```
align = Alignment(horizontal = 'left', vertical = 'center', wrap_text = True
IMAGECELL = ws.cell['A1']
IMAGECELL.alignment = align
```

This is my code for aligning text. It is not working with images.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "align images". OOXML has no concept of this.

Comment: align with respect to what?

Comment: I am trying to align them left with in their designated cell. As of now, when I insert the image into the cell, the image either overlaps the cell to the left of it or there is a gap between the cell boarder and image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78081736/13913019
Try this

Answer (score 0):

I know my solution is not perfect but it worked for me, just want to help others save time. I wanted to add multiple images too and align them but when I tried adding images they were placed on top of each other. It turned out that you have to use `anchors` in openpyxl to position images. and I wanted to put them in 2 x 3 Grid. Here's my solution.

```
def excel_writer(self, _location=None, images=None):
    if images is None or len(images) == 0:
        return
    for image in images:
        proto_image = Image(str(image))
        # A bit resizing
        proto_image.height = 250
        proto_image.width = 300

        if count == 0:
            proto_image.anchor = 'A3'
        if count == 1:
            proto_image.anchor = 'F3'
        if count == 2:
            proto_image.anchor = 'L3'
        if count == 3:
            proto_image.anchor = 'A20'
        if count == 4:
            proto_image.anchor = 'F20'
        if count == 5:
            proto_image.anchor = 'L20'
        if count == 6:
            proto_image.anchor = 'A43'

        sheet.add_image(proto_image, proto_image.anchor)
        count += 1

    workbook.save(_location)
```

So, I am going through a list of images and adding them on sheet at anchors position. For first image, the count is 0 and the anchor is A3; Which means 1st column, 3rd row. For 2nd image, same 3rd row but different column and so on.

One thing to notice is that I have calculated the space between columns manually. If your image is greater in width, you'll need to further move it along +ve x-axis like from  column A to L.

Comment: The OP wants to align an already anchored image within a cell. This answer is useless for this. So, it seems there's no precise placement of images within cells in `openpyxl`. I wonder, why even bother with `openpyxl` if `xlsxwriter` has this feature?